# Ubuntu can't mount / format formerly TrueCrypt encrypted SD card which works on Windows 8

Tags: mount, encryption, format, truecrypt, fat32

I have a 2GB SD card which I completely encrypted with TrueCrypt some time ago. However, I lost the key and there was no valuable data on it.

Windows 8 formatted it to fat32 without any problems and can use it normally, so I guess the card itself is okay.

However, Ubuntu won't mount or format it:

```
till@till-E5218:~$ sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0 /mnt/mmc-SD02G
mount: /dev/mmcblk0: can't read superblock

till@till-E5218:~$ sudo mkdosfs -n 'SD' -I /dev/mmcblk0
mkfs.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
mkdosfs: failed whilst writing reserved sector
```

There should be a way to get it working because it works in Windows - but I'm out of ideas now. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Try zeroing it out with dd. dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M

Comment: @mbiber Thanks for answering... That worked for me (after figuring out that I should leave out the "dd.")!

Comment: @mbiber However, it outputs an error: `dd: error writing ‘/dev/mmcblk0’: No space left on device
1933+0 records in
1932+0 records out
2026291200 bytes (2,0 GB) copied, 2,99529 s, 676 MB/s` Is that something I should be worried about or can it be ignored?

Comment: No need to worry, it says it doesn't have more space left which it does not since it's a 2GB card. I'll make it an answer so you can vote up :)

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense, now that I think about it... Sure! ;) Edit: If only I had 15 reputation to be allowed to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try zeroing the card out. This can easily be done with `dd` command.

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M`

This will write zeros to all memory cells inside the card making it completely blank.